# Paring program language with dynamic precedences?

Tags: python, parsing, prolog, operator-precedence, lepl

As you know in Prolog you can define precedence with op/3 dynamically.
I'm implementing myself Prolog in Python. Already have working prototype, but I still update the DB via limited python pseudo-prolog.
My next step is to implement the Parser. I can do static grammar w/o op-precedence.

My question how is precedence implemented in general ? Is there a word for it ?

It does not have to be fully dynamic op/3 i.e. I will be OK, even if I have to pre-load the op-table before I start parsing. 
I think I can modify the grammar via string manipulations beforehand.

I will probably use LEPL: http://www.acooke.org/lepl/ , if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the dynamic behaviour by means of a stack, extended by a 'Reduce' operation, that checks when an expression gets 'closed'. Working details [here](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL/blob/master/reduce.cpp), and [here](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL/blob/master/parse.cpp) for usage, but it's so simple that I would advise to start from scratch...

> My question how is precedence implemented in general ? Is there a word for it ?

I think the right word it's just that: precedence. As my teacher at compiler construction course suggested (so long ago), since dynamic definition isn't covered by standard algorithms for efficient parsing, just devise an 'ad hoc' approach. It's what I did in the linked source...

Comment: but doesn't your example implies I have to implement the parser myself ! I'm rather looking to leverage already existing parser ;(,  not reinvent the wheel.